# Elasticsearch 5.0.2 ignore_above gives unsupported parameter error

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new with Elasticsearch.  I am using ES version 5.0.2.  When I try to create mappings I got Unsupported parameters ignore_above..

Ignore above is a supported parameters in ES version 5.0.2.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myIndex?pretty' -d'
  "mappings":{
    "item":  {
      "properties" :  {
        "myreference":  {
          "type": "text", 
          "store": false, 
          "index":  "analyzed", 
          "analyzer":  "standard",
          "include_in_all":  false, 
          "ignore_above": 300, 
          "doc_values": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
'
```

If I added "null_value": "" to "myreference"  the error became 
unsupported parameters ["null_value"..., "ignore_above"...]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of ES 5, the `ignore_above` setting is not valid for `text` (i.e. analyzed) fields, but only for `keyword` fields. The same goes for `null_value`. You can find the confirmation of this [in this thread](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18086).

You can see a full example of how `ignore_above` works [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ignore-above.html) and how `null_value` works [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/null-value.html) and as you'll see they only work on `keyword` fields, not `text`ones.